# My for loop cannot find my array although I specified it

Tags: arrays, r, for-loop

I'm trying to plot a "3D matrix", that is, making the third line "times" (this is to show the average of errors multyplying). However, my array is not found by my for-loop. According to searches, I should declare the array first, but it doesn't help. Here's the first part of the process:

```
threed <- array(0,c(obsIndex,obsIndex,times))
for (j in 1:obsIndex) {
  for (k in 1:obsIndex) {
    if (j != k) {
      threed[j,k,1] <<- j * k
    }
  }
}
```

And the computer goes "object threed not found". How can it find it?

Comment: Change `<<-` to `<-`. Using `<<-` causes R to look in the parent environment, where there is no `threed`.

Comment: Replace your `<<-` with a single `<-`. The difference between these two are that the first will search outside e.g. a function's namespace for the variable. The latter will stay within the namespace. Always use `<-` (unless you know why you want the other variant).